# How to create a reactive formgroup based on any object

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to construct a formgroup based on any object(from api). Is it possible to assign that object directly to the formgroup?

**For example this is the object,**

```
parent: 'All', value: 1, children: [
            {
                parent: 'Programming', value: 91, children: [
                    {
                        parent: 'Frontend', value: 911, children: [
                            { parent: 'Angular 1', value: 9111 },
                            { parent: 'Angular 2', value: 9112 },
                            { parent: 'ReactJS', value: 9113, disabled: true }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        parent: 'Backend', value: 912, children: [
                            { parent: 'C#', value: 9121 },
                            { parent: 'Java', value: 9122 },
                            { parent: 'Python', value: 9123, checked: false, disabled: true }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                parent: 'Networking', value: 92, children: [
                    { parent: 'Internet', value: 921 },
                    { parent: 'Security', value: 922 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Finally the desired formgroup should be like this,**

```
form: {
  "username": "",
  "password": "",
  "treeView": {
    "All": null,
    "children": [
      "programming": "",
      "children": ["Angular 1": "","Angular 2": "", "ReactJS": "" ]   
     ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like this. need to use `formBuilder.array`

```
childArr : FormArray;

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  "username": "",
  "password": "",
  "treeView": this.formBuilder.group({
    "All": null,
    "children": this.childArr;
  })
});
```

you can push your obj using this line

this line put your response loop.

```
 (<FormArray>this.form.get('children')).push(new FormControl(obj))
```

Comment: I know this way. As I said in my question that the object is from api. So for any structure of object, I need to construct the formgroup.

Comment: formBuilder.group allowed object so you need to prepare using form group. parent child level fixed or N level?

Comment: Should be N level

Comment: What do you mean? I don’t understand.